# pg.so problem with Ruby in Windows

Tags: windows, ruby, module

I have installed the pg module with help of

```
gem install pg
```

Which returned

```
Successfully installed pg-0.8.0-x86-mswin32-60
```

When a .rb-file looks like this

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'pg'
```

I get an LoadError (exception 126) which tells me that it can't find the module C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/pg-0.8.0-x86-mswin32-60/lib/pg.so.

I heard something about that it is a Linux compilation. I'm really stuck so I really welcome suggestions.

I have also installed PostgreSQL, I use Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's not pg that's missing but some other dependency? Perhaps *devkit*?: http://blog.smajn.net/2009/07/installing-ruby-191-rails-232-and.html

Comment: I have now installed devkit as the blogpost has suggested, but on Ruby 1.8.6.

Answer (score 0):

pg gem depends on PostgreSQL DLL being in the PATH.

In case the required DLL is not found, Ruby will throw a loading error about pg.so

Please check that PostgreSQL binaries and DLL are in the PATH:

```
SET PATH
```

Or copy the required DLL (pq.dll) has been copied to Ruby installation directory.

I recommend read this blog article about setting PostgreSQL with new RubyInstaller (One-Click Installer successor):

[Install Ruby 1.9.1 and Rails 2.3.2 on Windows Vista](http://blog.smajn.net/2009/07/installing-ruby-191-rails-232-and.html)

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have added the path but can't find the .dll-file you mention. Maybe I just try to reinstall everything as the blogpost suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrestled with this myself.

1) Make sure C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\8.4\bin is in your path (as Luis suggested)
2) Make sure the libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll from C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\8.4\bin are loaded first.  In my case I copied them over from C:\ruby\bin, which (in my case) is first in my path.

I was getting errors like

> The ordinal 4046 could not be located in dynamic link library LIBEAY32.dll 
>   and
>   The ordinal 284 could not be located in the dynamic link library SSLEAY32.DLL

until I did step 2)

Good luck...